# Print all of the function arguments in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments

Here's my bare-bones plugin system:

```
 function DoPlugin() {
    $fargs = func_get_args();
    $type  = $fargs[0];
    $args  = range($fargs[1], $fargs[count($fargs)]);
    if(function_exists($type))
        call_user_func($type, $args);
    else
        echo "Function doesn't exist!";
    }

    function MyPlugin() {
    $fargs = func_get_args();
    $args    = range($fargs[0], $fargs[count($fargs)]);
    $strArgs = implode(" ", $args);
    echo $strArgs;
    }

    $args = array("MyPlugin", "Egg", "Milk");
    DoPlugin($args[0], range($args[1], $args[count($args)]));
```

It's supposed to call the function "DoPlugin", which then calls "MyPlugin" with all of the arguments and then "MyPlugin" prints them all separated by a space.

This is what it outputs:

```
1 0
```

This is what I want it to output:

```
Egg Milk
```

How can I print all of the arguments of a function, separated by a space?

Comment: `range()` already returns an array - so you have an array inside another array.

Comment: Updated post. It now outputs "1 0".

Comment: You need to seriously think about what exactly it is you want to do here. Are you expecting arguments passed to be one by one or grouped in an array? As it stands this is mixed up and probably causing you the unwanted result. Also use `array_shift()` if you want to seperate the first element of an array from the rest

Comment: I want to check if the first argument in an array is the same as a function, and if it is, call the function with the rest of the arguments. I also want the example function to print all of the arguments passed to it, separated by a space. Sorry if I'm being confusing, I've never been good at explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) instead of your custom function `DoPlugin`:

```
function MyPlugin(){
    echo implode(" ", func_get_args());
}

$args = array("MyPlugin", "Egg", "Milk");
call_user_func_array(array_shift($args), $args);
```

The output will be:

> `Egg Milk`

Demo: https://eval.in/99503

Comment: `DoPlugin($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);` < How do I pass all of the keys in $args? I'm expecting some arguments from the user and I don't know how many there'll be.

Comment: you can use `call_user_func` there as well: `call_user_func("DoPlugin", $args);` e.g.

Comment: @kingkero Cheers, it does exactly what I want now.

Comment: @Will Then can you mark it as accepted again? The trick here really is `call_user_func_array()` (=> `DoPlugin($arg0, $arg1, ...)` instead of `call_user_func()` (=> `DoPlugin( array($arg0, $arg1, ...) )`)

Answer (score 0):

```
DoPlugin() this your function
```

let assume you want to send two arguments  of this `DoPlugin();`

```
DoPlugin($arg1,$agr2)
```

send arguments  value when you call the function